# Adding cache layer to N-tier application instead of calling database multiple times in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, n-tier-architecture

In an n-tier application, in the business layer, I need to read database entities multiple times for validation purposes, so I decide to add caching layer to reduce the round trips to the database to fetch the data that will rarely change,
my question is where the caching layer should be added, or how the architecture should be,
to add caching layer without changing the whole architecture ( n-tier )

The layers:

```
API layer
   ||
Business Layer
   ||
Database Layer
```

Any recommendations or examples I can follow?

Comment: what are the details you want to know?

and what are the options you have?

Comment: You would probably need to post your entire project's source-code and then expect a random SO user to spend hours going through it all....

Comment: I don't think I need to do that, it's an architecture problem

Comment: You do, because you haven't told us _what exactly_ you want to cache or why you even think caching is necessary - for example, what performance tests and profiling, **exactly**, have you done to confirm that your database is a bottleneck in the first place? Why aren't you using EF's support for query batching to reduce the effective time-cost of database hits?

Comment: I mentioned I need to get the same entities multiple times, and these entities will rarely change, so why should hit the database multiple times while I can cache these entities? that is my question

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I think you don't understand what is my question

Comment: Your original question asks how to implement an entire cache-layer in-between your application-code and your "database layer" (I note that distinction between "business layer" and "database layer" is both arbitrary and incorrect: as your database layer will contain business logic, and it isn't a true "layer" either - you're just using EF, so you're overselling it) but in the comments you say you want to cache a limited number of entities that are kept in-memory). If this is a misunderstanding of your question then please be specific about what you think I've misunderstood.

Comment: yes, I want to add caching layer to cache some entities, without sharing the business logic between the database and business layer.

Comment: "without share the business between the database and business layer" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I don't want to make the database layer know anything about the caching layer or what entities should be cached

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.